# Are vector bundles special cases of étale bundles?

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Is it possible to define vector bundles as particular instances of étale bundles?

An étale bundle is a bundle $p:E\rightarrow X$ which is a local homeomorphism (as in Maclane-Moerdijk): every $e\in E$ has an open neighborhood $V$ s.t $p(V)$ is open in $X$ and $p|_V$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by étale bundle?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez a bundle $p:E\rightarrow X$ which is a local homeomorphism (as in Maclane-Moerdijk): every $e\in E$ has an open neighborhood $V$ s.t $p(V)$ is open in $X$ and $p|_V$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Please add such clarifications to the body of the question.

Comment: Sheaves are equivalent to étale bundles, and locally free sheaves are equivalent to vector bundles. How does this settle with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Nontrivial vector bundles are never étale.

From Maclane-Moerdijk p88:

[image]

Comment: This is false by the way.  You can have a topological vector bundle with discrete fibres  by ignoring the topology on R.  What is true is that smooth vector bundles are never étale.