# Equivalence of sheaves and various categories of bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

The following equivalences are well-established:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Locally-free sheaves on }X &\leftrightarrow \text{Vector bundles over }X\\
\cap\qquad & \qquad\qquad\textbf{?}\\
\text{Sheaves on }X &\leftrightarrow \text{Étalé spaces over }X\\
\cup\qquad & \qquad\qquad\cup\\
\text{Locally-constant sheaves on }X &\leftrightarrow \text{Covering spaces over }X
\end{align}$$

Further, the ways that we construct a sheaf from a vector bundle and from an étalé space are 'identical': we just take the sheaf of sections of the projection map.
But it is [also known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1395919/71510) that a non-trivial vector bundle is never étalé. This makes me confused/intrigued about two things:

1. Why does the equivalence of categories (sheaves$\leftrightarrow$étalé) not descend to the equivalence (locally-free sheaves$\leftrightarrow$something) in the same way that it does for locally-constant sheaves and covering spaces? (i.e. why are the bottom two rows of this diagram 'nice' while the top two are 'not nice'?)
2. Given some vector bundle, we can associate to it (uniquely?) a sheaf, to which we can then associate an étalé space (and vice versa). Does this give us an equivalence of categories (vector bundles$\leftrightarrow$some sort of étalé spaces)?

Comment: What you say is essentially correct but you have to distinguish between $X$ being a topological space, a scheme, some type of manifold or a general (locally?) ringed space and also be precise about whether you are studying sheaves of sets, of abelian groups, of vector spaces, of $\mathcal O_X$-Modules.

Answer (score 1):

The top two are different because you're only looking at the module, and forgetting the ring.

The category of sheaves over $X$ doesn't remember how $\mathbb{R}$ looks as a topological space; it only understands the sheaf $C_X$ of continuous real-valued functions, and the ring structure of that sheaf.

The étalé space of $C_X$ doesn't look *anything* like $\mathbb{R}$.

Under the sheaf-étalé space correspondence, a sheaf of real vector spaces doesn't become a real vector bundle: it becomes a module over the étalé space of $C_X$.